# toCharArray in Java works but sum of elements not

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, recursion, character

I am testing the following piece of code:

```
    static int superDigit(String n, int k) {
    char[] concatenatedN = n.toCharArray();        
    int superDigit = 0;
    int sumDigits = 0;
    char[] totalSum;

    if (n.length() > 0) {
        sumDigits = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < concatenatedN.length; j++) {
            sumDigits = sumDigits + (int)concatenatedN[j]; 
            System.out.println(" sumDigits: " + sumDigits + " ,concatenatedN[j]: " + concatenatedN[j]);
        }      
        totalSum = String.valueOf(sumDigits * k).toCharArray();
        superDigit = sumDigitsRecursive(totalSum);

    } //end if
    return superDigit;
}
```

For some reason that I don't know sumDigits variable must be the sum of array elements (concatenatedN[j]) but something weird happens and instead of sum, the following output is showed (when I do System.out.println):

```
 sumDigits: 53 ,concatenatedN[j]: 5
 sumDigits: 104 ,concatenatedN[j]: 3
 sumDigits: 154 ,concatenatedN[j]: 2
 sumDigits: 203 ,concatenatedN[j]: 1
```

Result must be ---> array is 5,3,2,1 ---> result = 5 + 3 + 2 + 1

Comment: When casting a `char` to an `int` it will return the ascii code of the char, which is not what you want

Comment: Show what you expect instead and what your actual inputs are. Also, don't forget to debug yourself before asking. SO is not a free debugging service.

Comment: You could discover this for yourself if you printed the individual values in the array as you added them up.  The first `53` = 5 is a hint.  http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you cast a `char` to an `int` it gets converted to its underlying int value, which is its [acsii](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) value. This is clearly not what you want. Instead you can use [`Character.getNumericValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(int)) to get the `int` value:

```
sumDigits = sumDigits + Character.getNumericValue(concatenatedN[j]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the numeric unicode values of the characters of the string. Luckily, these values are consecutive, so you can convert these face values to the numbers they represent by subtracting the values of `'0'`:

```
for (int j = 0; j < concatenatedN.length; j++) {
    sumDigits = sumDigits + (int)(concatenatedN[j] - '0'); 
}
```